# What is the next pattern?

Tags: logical-deduction

This is taken from a certain rather popular IQ test:

[image]

Which of the four figure on the right completes the series on the left, and most importantly, WHY?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's ...

> ... the third symbol with the 7 points.
>
>  The first three symbols have 2, 3 and 5 points. These numbers are the first three primes. The next prime number is 7. (This answer doesn't say anything about how the strokes should be placed.)

Comment: Why the difference between thick and thin lines?  Arbitrary that vertical and horizontal are thin and diagonal are thick?  And orientation is simply ignored... Really?